# Mirth - Add new field to OBR 16 segment

Tags: javascript, hl7, mirth

Got an opportunity to work in Mirth to add an entry in the OBR field.
With the help of this forum, I was able to edit an existing data, that works perfectly fine.
But failing to add a data to a field which doesn't exist in the source HL7. 
Below is the example,

SourceHL7

```
PV2|||||||System Alert Off~0437689973~ABC-KOTHAI-AUS
OBR|1||ABCDEDFGH|754051^ABCEDEF^MDC|||20190225133500+0000||||||||||||||||||F
```

In the DestinationHL7, I want to check if PV2.7.2 has "KOTHAI", if yes, then update the OBR.16 as below

```
OBR|1||ABCDEDFGH|754051^ABCEDEF^MDC|||20190225133500+0000|||||||||KOTHAI|||||||||F
```

With the below Javascript, I am able to see the last value in OBR is changed as M but no "KOTHAI" is available.  I could see the change in Transformed data but not in Encoded data. Could you let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
 tmp=msg; 
var code = tmp['ORU_R01.PATIENT_RESULT']['ORU_R01.PATIENT']['ORU_R01.VISIT']['PV2']['PV2.7'][2].toString();
if (code.indexOf("ARSTALL") != -1 )
{

tmp['ORU_R01.PATIENT_RESULT']['ORU_R01.ORDER_OBSERVATION']['OBR']['OBR.25'] = "M";
tmp['ORU_R01.PATIENT_RESULT']['ORU_R01.ORDER_OBSERVATION']['OBR']['OBR.16'] = "KOTHAI";
}else {

tmp['ORU_R01.PATIENT_RESULT']['ORU_R01.ORDER_OBSERVATION']['OBR']['OBR.25'] = "F";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same answer I gave on your forum post http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=218996

You're using the strict parser, so you need to make sure everything is named correctly depending on hl7 datatype.

I think you want to do this:

```
tmp['ORU_R01.PATIENT_RESULT']['ORU_R01.ORDER_OBSERVATION']['OBR']['OBR.16']['XCN.1'] = "KOTHAI";
```

Comment: Hi Tony, 
Thank you, I am yet to try this out, will keep you posted if I get access to the server again.